# Looping an executable to get the result from Python script

Tags: python, linux, executable, system-calls

In my python script, I need to call within a for loop an executable, and waiting for that executable to write the result on the "output.xml".

How do I manage to use wait() & how do I know when one of my executable is finished generating the result to get the result? How do I close that process and open a new one to call again the executable and wait for the new result?

```
    import subprocess
    args = ("bin/bar")
    popen = subprocess.Popen(args)
```

I need to wait for the output from "bin/bar" to generate the "output.xml" and from there, read it's content.

```
    for index, result in enumerate(results):
        myModule.callSubProcess(index)
        #this is where the problem is.
        fileOutput = open("output.xml")
        parseAndStoreInSQLiteFileOutput(index, file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Popen.wait()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) will make the script wait until the process ends. There's no need to kill the process afterwards, since it will have already exited.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do is using `call`:

```
import subprocess
retcode = subprocess.call('command', shell=True)
```

It waits for the process to terminate and assign the return code to the variable.
For more detailed description see [17.1.subprocess - convenience functions](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#convenience-functions) in the python documentation. Hope it helps.